# One-Way Speed of Light - Einstein-Ring-Like Setup Solves It?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k) video that introduced the concept of the one-way speed of light.

Now, that got me thinking: wouldn't an Einstein-ring-like setup, where light would be bent 360 degrees from a source point on the ring, and travel around the ring back to the source, solve it?

The setup is this:

- A high-enough mass object to be able to bend incoming light by 360 degrees, such that light would travel in an ring around the mass
- A light source on the ring, with a speedometer on its opposite side (180 degrees compared to the light emission angle)

Then, light would get emitted from the source, travel in a ring around the mass, and end up on the other side of the emitter to be measured by the speedometer.

Wouldn't this setup solve the problem? Unless there are any issues to it? The only limitation that I can think of is that this *might* be only possible with a dark hole's even horizon - since only that would be massive enough to bend the light by 360 degrees (since it's posssible for it to bend that much only if it's not able to escape), but I'm not sure if that's true.

And if that's true, what if the black hole were to shrink - the space the light would go through would be less curved, and then the light would be able to escape the event horizon, and its whole trajectory from the moment of entering the black hole would be straight  - just in a curved space. Wouldn't **that** solve the problem?

Comment: The tricky part might be in how to measure the length of the looped path.

Comment: I suppose that could be measured in advance. It's already done with black holes, no? We know radii of various black holes.

Comment: Maybe.  But substituting a black hole for a mirror doesn't exactly make it a one-way measurement.

Comment: Why not? The direction of the light doesn't change. It's still a straight line.

Comment: Ok, how would you propose measuring the distance?  And remember you need to take into account the fact that distances and clock rates act funny near a black hole.